# Do not send response headers at all

Tags: tomcat, jetty, apache-camel, response-headers

I have tiny Java web application backed by Apache Camel. It uses Camel's servlet component. This application is meant to be connector and receive data from devices.

As far as we pay for traffic I am interesting if there is a way to deny all response headers from web server and send only status code.

**Update:**

```
from("servlet:///channel?servletName=ChannelServlet")

...

.split().method("objectSplitter", "splitRootObject")
.log("before removeHeaders")
.removeHeaders("*")
.log("after removeHeaders")
.process(new Processor() {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message out = exchange.getOut();
        out.removeHeaders("*");
        out.setHeader("custom", "custom");
        out.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, "200");
        out.setBody("");
        LOG.debug("In processor");
    }
});
```

I am always receiving:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: localhost:8080
charset: utf-8
breadcrumbId: ID-eclipse-46977-1369749855622-0-2
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_21
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Jetty(7.6.8.v20121106)
```

At the end of stacktrace:

```
[          http-bio-9080-exec-5] route1                         INFO  before removeHeaders
[          http-bio-9080-exec-5] Tracer                         INFO  ID-eclipse-43869-1369751726247-0-12 >>> (route1) log[before removeHeaders] --> removeHeaders[*] <<< Pattern:InOut, Headers:{frame=0, imei=393090335172229, type=SdkMsgFrame, genTime=0, breadcrumbId=ID-eclipse-43869-1369751726247-0-11, key=2aa4678e-2eb8-42c2-9b59-2e816c276cd5, numFrames=1}, BodyType:String, Body:eNo1...Q1GJ+
[          http-bio-9080-exec-5] Tracer                         INFO  ID-eclipse-43869-1369751726247-0-12 >>> (route1) removeHeaders[*] --> log[after removeHeaders] <<< Pattern:InOut, BodyType:String, Body:eNo1...Q1GJ+
[          http-bio-9080-exec-5] route1                         INFO  after removeHeaders
[          http-bio-9080-exec-5] Tracer                         INFO  ID-eclipse-43869-1369751726247-0-12 >>> (route1) log[after removeHeaders] --> com.succorfish.harbour.http.route.ServletRoute$1@17968bee <<< Pattern:InOut, BodyType:String, Body:eNo1...Q1GJ+
[          http-bio-9080-exec-5] ServletRoute                   DEBUG In processor
[          http-bio-9080-exec-5] MulticastProcessor             DEBUG Done sequential processing 1 exchanges
```

Comment: Be careful, you don't want to remove ALL of the headers, otherwise your HTTP client will not know how to decode the response data, and it would certainly break any sort of HTTP/1.1 pipelining.  If you want to save network bytes, then trade CPU for network bytes and compress the response using the standard HTTP Gzip response encoding.

Comment: No seriously, I just want my web server to do not send any headers. Is that so complex? Should I consider TCP instead?

Comment: The headers on HTTP are there for a reason, many of the headers are mandated (with various response headers in the MUST and REQUIRED level of compliance outlined by RFC2119).  You can easily break a client, or a firewall, or a load balancer by removing required response headers.

Comment: Maybe you should consider cometd or websocket to maintain a long lived connection for bi-directional messaging.  These have very small overhead once established (websocket's per frame overhead is from 2 bytes to 28 bytes depending on the the origin and type of websocket frame)

Comment: As a followup example, if your clients are on any mobile networks, and you remove all of the HTTP response headers, you *will* break the HTTP exchange.  This is because all mobile networks send their traffic through caching transparent HTTP gateway proxies, and you just broke the HTTP spec (aka contract).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer to this question is that you can remove most of headers from Camel but Tomcat/Jetty will append some of them anyway. The smallest headers I have got were:

```
Date: Thu, 30 May 2013 09:49:30 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Length: 0
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

This is still unacceptable in my case, so I will use Apache Mina and UDP/TCP instead of HTTP.

Comment: `Date` and `Server` are not added by Jetty.  Also, the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is incompatible with `Content-Length: 0` as `Transfer-Encoding` is used for content without a length defined (at least that's how it works in Jetty), but you have one in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Camel to remove all headers at the end of the route. Then the response dont have any headers.

```
from("jetty:...")
   ...
   .removeHeaders("*");
```

See some of these pages also

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-remove-the-http-protocol-headers-in-the-camel-message.html
- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-avoid-sending-some-or-all-message-headers.html